# "How not to write an NSF proposal" poster: does any one know where to find it online?

Tags: grants, career, soft-question

When I was recently at MSRI, they had a big poster of humorous advice on how to get an NSF proposal rejected (for example: "Definitely don't worry about sending it to an appropriate program officer.  Surely it will find its way to the right person eventually.").  I thought it was a very good summation of how to write a proposal.  But I just tried to find it on Google, and failed (probably because I'm not remembering what the real title was).

> Does anyone know where this list is available online?

Comment: I don't know where to find the exact poster that was at MSRI, but there's a very similar one for astronomy: http://wia2009.gsfc.nasa.gov/contributed_posters/full_posters/poster27.pdf

Comment: Hmm, that looks awfully similar to the one at MSRI.  It does seem a little weird that it's astronomy (maybe the one I saw was a ripoff?)

Comment: Why don't you ask the MSRI staff?  They surely must know this.

Comment: The poster seems good.

Comment: Pretty criptic poster, some entries not comprehensible to me, either as a joke or seriously. Font also hard to read. If it is a proposal for a joke foundation I would not fund the joker.

Comment: The person who arranges posters is not in yet today. I sent her an email and voicemail. If it is alright with msri I will most likely send you a pdf individually and you can decide what to do with it. Meanwhile, to forestall awkward questions, I have no official standing at msri since Irving Kaplansky died, I just know everyone and use the library and computers.

Comment: Thanks!  Don't worry too much about it; I will definitely survive if it is not obtained.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of this poster but there is a funny lecture by Serre: "How to Write Mathematics Badly" which may be of some relevance.
http://modular.fas.harvard.edu/edu/basic/serre/